# in ms access-attempting to use one field to populate other fields in a form

Tags: ms-access

LATEST UPDATE (Mon Night)

First, I successfully display and select from my city_table, populating the
city_no on the form

I am then attempting to use that value to extract/use the city_nm and
state_nm on the same form.

I coded this as the (modified) afterupdate code for city_no.

```
Private Sub city_no_AfterUpdate()  
Dim got_city_nm, got_state_nm  
got_city_nm = DLookup("[city_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")  
got_city_nm = DLookup("city_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
city_nm = got_city_nm  
got_state_nm = DLookup("[state_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")  
got_state_nm = DLookup("state_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
state_nm = got_state_nm  
seat_no = "XXX"  
End Sub
```

Still nothing happens including the last statement (assigning "XXX" to seat_no)

So I simplified it to just try that by itself:

```
Private Sub city_no_AfterUpdate()  
seat_no = "XXX"  
End Sub
```

Still nothing. I'm clearly missing something simple and trivial.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but it has no meaning to me and I have not one tiny clue what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `RecordSource` property of the City Name textbox to:

`=DLookup("[city_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")`.

Then set the `RecordSource` property of the State Name textbox to:

`=DLookup("[state_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")`

Comment: Should be `city_no` without the quotes