# How to get an AfterUpdate procedure to update other fields in the same form

Tags: ms-access, vba

As of Wednesday morning ...

First, I successfully display and select from my city_table, populating the city_no on the form

I am then attempting to use that value to extract/use the city_nm and state_nm on the same form.

I coded this as the (modified) afterupdate code for city_no.

```
Private Sub city_no_AfterUpdate()  
Dim got_city_nm, got_state_nm  
got_city_nm = DLookup("[city_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")  
got_city_nm = DLookup("city_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
city_nm = got_city_nm  
got_state_nm = DLookup("[state_nm]", "city_table", "[city_no]" = "city_no")  
got_state_nm = DLookup("state_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
state_nm = got_state_nm  
seat_no = "XXX"  
End Sub
```

Still nothing happens including the last statement (assigning "XXX" to seat_no)

So I simplified it to just try that by itself:

```
Private Sub city_no_AfterUpdate()  
seat_no = "XXX"  
End Sub
```

Still nothing. I'm clearly missing something simple and trivial. I appreciate all the help. I've been working on this in my spare time as a personal project, using Access/VBA for the first time. I have about 4 hours into this project trying to learn it from public sources.

Comment: Is your textbox `city_no` bound?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in ms access-attempting to use one field to populate other fields in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518030/in-ms-access-attempting-to-use-one-field-to-populate-other-fields-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the VBA window and click in the left margin of the code.  It will put a red dot in the margin.  This is called a "break point".  Run your form and make your change, and the code will stop where the break point is and highlight that line in yellow.  To continue running through the code, press F8.  This will run the lines of code one at a time and allow you to see exactly what's being processed.

When you get to each line of code, "hover" your mouse over the variables from the current and previous lines to see what the application THINKS the variable is equal to.  You may find that what you think and what the app thinks are two different things at times.

If the code jumps over a bunch of lines and goes straight to the End Sub, you've got an error on the last line it highlighted.

Using this methodology is PARAMOUNT to understanding how VBA works.  I've been working with it for 20 years and I still do this when I can't figure out what's wrong.  See if this helps you answer your own question.  If not, hopefully it will at least pinpoint a line of code that's not working properly and you can come back and ask a specific question about it.

EDIT: A quick look at the code makes me wonder something; is City_No a NUMBER or a TEXT?  Because if it's a NUMBER, you want to get rid of the single quote around the variable.  Text needs single quotes, numbers don't.

FURTHER EDIT: I think you need something more like this:

```
Private Sub city_no_AfterUpdate()  
Dim got_city_nm, got_state_nm  
got_city_nm = DLookup("city_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
Me.city_nm.Value = got_city_nm  
got_state_nm = DLookup("state_nm", "city_table", "city_no='" & Me.city_no & "'")  
Me.state_nm.Value = got_state_nm  
seat_no = "XXX"  
End Sub
```

If you're trying to fill in the value of a control (i.e. textbox), you need to reference it with "Me." (if it's on the same form) or "Forms!MyFormName." (if it's on another form).

Comment: Most helpful. Most thorough. I truly thank you for the time and effort. To answer your question, city_no is TEXT (e.g. 'c102', 'S008' depending on which Wikipedia table is the original source). Thank you again.

Comment: AHA 
Your revised code works much better SORT OF. The issue (FINALLY!) is that the setting of the city_nm, state_nm and seat_no only happen if I "manipulate" the chosen city from the table. Example, if I first select the city from the table, and then add and delete a space after the city_nm code it works. But it does NOT work if I ONLY select the city from the table. So, to my feeble brain it appears that modifying the selected city triggers the AfterUpdate procedure but just selecting a city does not.

Further explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: PS (and thanks for the nudge by the way ... I'm changing the name of city_no to city_cd and similar for seat_no)

Comment: James - If the answer is helpful, please either click the up arrow next to it or the checkmark (or both, if you're feeling generous).  It awards me points, which allow me to have additional functionality on this site.  Also, keep that in mind for any future questions you post here.  Thanks!

Comment: To answer your follow-up, try putting it in the OnChange event. That should trigger as soon as you select something from the drop-down. But it may also have unwanted functionality (i.e. if the dropdown is one where you can begin typing a word, it's going to fire with every keystroke).

Comment: check mark clicked; I don't have enough whatevers for an uptick but certainly will if/when I get the magic beans. 

Will make next change and report back.

Comment: Cancel that last comment, because it doesn't look like you're using a dropdown (aka Combo) box.  But it definitely sounds like you might need a different "event" to trigger.  Possibly OnChange or IsDirty instead of AfterUpdate.  Do a little Google on VBA events because a lot of them sound very similar.

Comment: When you get to it; how exactly are you selecting the value?  Are you, in fact, using a combo box?  This is a pretty good description of the event process, take a look at the section "Changing and Updating Data in a Control": http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HA010238988.aspx  If that doesn't answer your question, come on back and let me know how your city is selected.

Comment: I'm now in deep doo doo. when I changed the name of the field in the tables, the names in the forms also changed. I then changed the names in the procedure code and I'm getting errors that the new fields are not recognized. Do I have to start over completely?

Comment: I thought I was using a combo box? what do I click where to have the system tell me what the box is?

Comment: It is a LIST BOX. Should I use a COMBO BOX and what is the difference?

Comment: LOL ... first the system here tells me to avoid extended discussions in comments and asks me if I want to move it to chat. Then when I say "yes", it tells me I don't have enough pringles to chat. No ding to YOU, but for ME, that is poor design.

so I'll keep adding to these comments. Now I'm learning about combo boxes and seeing it that helps me or hurts me.

Comment: A list box basically displays a full, scrollable list at all times, while a combo box takes up as much space as a text box but allows you to display a fully scrollable list. For the most part, it's personal preference. Although, if you need to display multiple columns then working with a list box is probably easier. If it's a list box, there's an OnClick event that is probably where you want to put that code.

Comment: office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/… is an excellent REFERENCE. That said, there is too much information there for me to even know what part to read to learn the next thing. Part of the perils of learning by doing as opposed to doing after learning. I don't need to know it all, I just need the next nugget. I'm not trying to write a secure enterprise application for others, I'm trying to assemble a tiny database to help me collect a little data. [end of rant]

Comment: PROGRESS AND MICRO SUCCESS THANKS TO YOU. THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH. TODAY IS NOW LISTED AS A GOOD DAY!